# python count how many 1 in the 3rd column of top 9 rows?

Tags: python, csv, count

Assuming we have this csv

```
a,0.900,1,1
b,0.895,1,2
c,0.893,1,3
d,0.881,1,4
e,0.879,1,5
f,0.875,1,6
g,0.875,0,7
h,0.875,0,8
i,0.869,0,9
j,0.865,1,10
k,0.862,1,11
```

Is there any efficient and correct way to count how many 1 in the 3rd column of top 9 rows?

Here is my incorrect code:

```
current_file="column3.csv"

file=open(current_file,'r')

a_count=[];

count = 0

for line in csv.reader(file):

        while (count <= n-1):

            a_count.append(int(line[2]));   

            count=count+1

a=sum(a_count)                                  

print a_count

print a
```

Incorrect Output here

```
a_count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

a=9
```

Desired output:

```
a_count=[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

a=6
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code to get desired output

```
import csv


n=9
file=open("filename",'r')
a_count = []
count = 0

for line in csv.reader(file):
    print line[1]
    if(line[2]=="1"):
        a_count.append(int(line[2]));
    else:
        a_count.append(0);
    count=count+1
    if(count==9):
        break

a=sum(a_count)                                  
print a_count
print a
```

output:

```
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
        6
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('column3.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   rows = list(reader)

print(sum(int(i[2]) for i in rows[:9]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code also,

```
>>> with open('file.csv') as f:
    l = []
    count = int(0)
    for line in csv.reader(f):
        l.append(int(line[2]))
    m = l[:9]
    for i in m:
        if i==1:
            count=count+1
    print(m)
    print(count)


[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
6
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Both answers are decent. Dont know who I should vote to.lol

Comment: Choose an answer which was easily understandable :-)